# Java Socket Multithreading Server; Chatting

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Server.java:

```
private Socket connection;
  private int ID;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  int port = 19999;
  int count = 0;
    try{
      ServerSocket socket1 = new ServerSocket(port);

      System.out.println("Server Initialized");
      while (true) {
        Socket connection = socket1.accept();
        Runnable runnable = new Server(connection, ++count);
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
  }
Server(Socket s, int i) {
  this.connection = s;
  this.ID = i;//could use a client name as it is individual id for each thread.?
}
public void run() {
    try {
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), true);

       String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                Process p = new Process();
                String output = p.input(inputLine);
                out.println(output);
                }
            }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    finally {
      try {
        connection.close();
     }
      catch (IOException e){}
    }
}
}
```

When run it creates a server, which when connected to by a client creates a thread for it so that it can handle multiple clients at one time.

However the code:

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    Process p = new Process();
                    String output = p.input(inputLine);
                    out.println(output);
                    }
```

loops the BufferedReader to get all the input given from the client. and when receives processes it and then sends the reply back to the client to be printed.

how can i get it so that i can send/get another question via the client at the same time as the first?

e.g

"user: hello computer how are you?"
"computer:I am good, how are you?"
"user: i am good"
"computer: that is nice to hear"

works fine. but:

"user: was is 1+1?"
"computer: 1+1=2"
"computer: any more question?"
"user: good?"

does not.

**how can do it so that the server give multiple answers rather than having to wait for another input?**

It would be easy to do if i set output as a string in server.java however every time i try to access the string to change it
(by using
`Server s = new Server(); s.output = "stuff";`) as the code suggests it just makes a new thread server. how can i access the already made thread?

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the client thread into a kind of map and if you need to send a message to another thread, you could look up the map and get the reference to the other thread and send message from there.

Comment: seems like a good idea but accessing the map in the server class would create a new thread

Comment: Not necessarily a new thread. You could use the existing client thread to access the map. The map itself could be located within the main server thread.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do. One example (I'm not saying this is the best approach) is to create an hashmap in the server thread with public static modifier. The hashmap will map between client id and the client thread it is associated with.